# Adding in additional pages into a custom theme

Tags: pages

I have a simple site with a landing page and 2 additional pages( About, Work).  I  used front-page.php for the landing page.  I'm not sure the best practice for adding in the additional pages.  Currently I have just added a page for each and added in the custom html.  I don't feel this is the best way so I wanted to get some advice on how to handle this.

Would page templates be a good use case for this?  It would be nice to possibly be able to add in a form on one of the pages via plugin, so I'm not sure how I would mix that in with custom html.

Thank you

Comment: You don't have to hardcode menus in themes, are these pages as in you went into WP Admin and added a page? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I'm not hard coding the menus.  Currently, yes I added 2 pages and just pasted in my custom html.  I feel like this might not be the best practice?

Comment: It's suboptimal, but it works, it's very difficult to advise on best practice though without knowing more about your situation, so the best answer you could hope for right now is.. it might be

Comment: Sorry... I wanted to clarify and see what you think.  I have header and footer and menus working the right way. I have a page.php set up to handle single pages. If I have an html file for an about page.... what would a best practice be for handling this page?  Create a page via dashboard and use html blocks?  I have no blog on my site. I think I’m over thinking it and making more difficult than necessary. If I explained it any better and you could advise right or wrong I would be appreciative. Thank you